# How can I create a random 2d array in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, random, functional-programming

I am fairly new to Haskell and I'm always confused when it comes to dealing with random values. This time I'm trying to create a 5x5 2d-array in which every cell contains a random value between 4 options.

```
data Content = Bomb | One | Two | Three deriving (Eq, Show)
data Board = Array (Int, Int) Cell
data Cell = Cell {
   content :: Content,
   state :: CellState,
   notes :: Notes
}
type Notes = [String]
type CellState = Bool
```

then in the main function I typed

```
main :: IO()
main = do
let cellMatrix = createMatrix
print cellMatrix
```

How can I create a function that creates a Board, and where do I need to do all the g<-newStdGen stuff?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `data Board = Array (Int, Int) Cell` doesn't do what you think it does. You're trying to do too many new things at once: create data structures with multiple fields, create arrays, and use randomness. Pick just one to focus on.

Answer (score 2):

Focusing solely on the **randomness** aspect of the problem here, we see that the [System.Random](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.2.1.1/docs/System-Random.html) module in its version 1.2 provides an `uniformR` function that can produce one pseudo-random integer value from a specified range. Typically, we would need 5*5=25 values from the (0,3) range.

**Side Note:** Beware the changes between `Random` v1.1 and v1.2 are [massive ones](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/hefgxa/ann_random120_a_long_overdue_upgrade/).

Alternatively, the same module provides a `randomRs` function, but that one provides an infinite list of integer values, hence cannot return an updated value of the generator. That might not be what you require.

We can use as our workhorse a function that returns a finite count of random *integer* values, together with an updated generator:

```
import  System.Random

getManyInts :: RandomGen g => g -> Int -> (Int,Int) -> ([Int],g)
getManyInts g0 count range =
    if (count <= 0)  then  ([], g0) 
                     else  let 
                                (v,g1)  = uniformR range g0
                                (vs,gf) = getManyInts g1 (count-1) range
                           in        
                                (v:vs, gf)
```

In order to navigate from integer to Enum values, we will use a slightly improved `Content` type:

```
data Content = Bomb | One | Two | Three
               deriving (Eq, Show, Enum, Bounded)
```

At that point, we can write a small test program that provides 5*5=25 random values of `Content` type:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    g0 <- newStdGen
    let  count = 5*5
         (loC, hiC) = (minBound :: Content, maxBound :: Content)
         intRange   = (fromEnum loC, fromEnum hiC)
         (xs, g1)   = getManyInts g0 count intRange
         cs         = (map toEnum xs) :: [Content]

    putStrLn $ "contents: " ++ (show cs)
```

**Test program output:**

```
contents: [Two,Three,One,One,One,Two,One,Two,One,Bomb,Two,Two,One,Three,Bomb,Two,Two,Bomb,Three,One,One,Bomb,One,One,Bomb]
```

### Addendum:

**A better, polymorphic function:**

Next, we can provide a function that returns a list of random values for any similar type:

```
{-#  LANGUAGE  ScopedTypeVariables  #-}
{-#  LANGUAGE  ExplicitForAll       #-}

getManyEnums :: forall g e. (RandomGen g, Bounded e, Enum e) => g -> Int -> ([e],g)
getManyEnums g0 count = (map toEnum xs, g1) 
  where
    intRange   = (fromEnum (minBound :: e), fromEnum (maxBound :: e)) 
    (xs, g1)   = getManyInts g0 count intRange
```

This function can be specialized as required. For example:

**Testing under ghci:**

```
$ ghci
 GHCi, version 8.10.5: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
 ...
 λ> 
 λ> :load q73268595.hs
 [1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( q73268595.hs, interpreted )
 Ok, one module loaded.
 λ> 
 λ> getManyContents = getManyEnums :: StdGen -> Int ->  ([Content],StdGen)
 λ> 
 λ> g0 <- newStdGen
 λ> 
 λ> (cs,gf) = getManyContents g0 10
 λ> 
 λ> cs
 [One,One,Two,One,One,Three,Three,Three,Bomb,One]
 λ> 
 λ> :q
Leaving GHCi.
$
```